# Prevent ordering in gRaphael pie chart

Tags: javascript, canvas, raphael, graphael

I'm trying to draw two pie charts using `gRaphael`, like so:

```
var r = new Raphael(0, 0, '100%', '100%'); 

r.piechart(100,120,80,[60,40]);
r.piechart(300,120,80,[40,60]);
```

This produces the following picture:

[image: Mmmmmm, pie]

The two pie charts are identical even though the order of the arguments I passed to `r.piechart` is different. Is there any way I can prevent this from happening so that one of the charts will have the 60% blue slice on the bottom and the other one will remain as it is?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amitaviv99/TBzg3/). I'm not a gRaphael expert, so there might be a better way.. I changed the piechart function (line 99 of g.pie.js) from

```
values.sort(function (a, b) {
    return b.value - a.value;
});
```

to

```
if (opts.sort !== false) {
    values.sort(function (a, b) {
        return b.value - a.value;
    });
}
```

And than changed your code to:

```
r.piechart(100,120,80,[60,40], {sort: false});
r.piechart(300,120,80,[40,60], {sort: false});
```

Comment: Note, however, that if you use MinPercent or MaxSlices, they rely on the values being sorted for correct functionality. Better to _add_ code that puts it back in the original order:
`if (opts.sort == false) {
    values.sort(function(a, b) {
        return a.order - b.order;
    });
}`

Right after the line starting with `others && values.splice...`.